# mySQL ORDER BY SUM of double GROUP BY, preserve groups

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Here's the question: I have a table that looks like this (simplified)

```
+------+------+------+
| res  | loc  | rent |
+------+------+------+
| WEB  | WP   |  100 |
| WEB  | VA   |  300 |
| VR   | WP   |  500 |
| VR   | VA   |  200 |
| VR   | VA   |  600 | 
| CS   | WP   |  400 | 
| CS   | WP   |   90 |
+------+------+------+
```

I can get the table to look like this with SELECT res, loc, SUM(rent) FROM testTable GROUP BY res, loc;

```
+------+------+-----------+
| res  | loc  | SUM(rent) |
+------+------+-----------+
| CS   | WP   |       490 |
| VR   | VA   |       800 |
| VR   | WP   |       500 |
| WEB  | VA   |       300 |
| WEB  | WP   |       100 |
+------+------+-----------+
```

What I want from here is to order the table with VR first (because its TOTAL rent is largest), then CS , then, WEB but I also want to preserve group order so it'd look like this

```
+------+------+-----------+
| res  | loc  | SUM(rent) |
+------+------+-----------+
| VR   | VA   |       800 |
| VR   | WP   |       500 |
| CS   | WP   |       490 |
| WEB  | VA   |       300 |
| WEB  | WP   |       100 |
+------+------+-----------+
```

This way they're summed rent grouped by location and then ordered by largest rent total and then ordered by rent within that rent total. VR is top cause (800 + 500) > 490 > (300 + 100) and loc VA comes before WP in the VR group because 800 > 500.

Is this possible am I dreaming too big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to calculate the total for the res values separately in a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT t.res, t.loc, SUM(t.rent) AS reslocRent
FROM table AS t
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT res, SUM(rent) AS resRent
   FROM table
   GROUP BY res
) AS subQ ON t.res = subQ.res
GROUP BY t.res, t.loc
ORDER BY subQ.resRent DESC, reslocRent DESC
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted thanks. However, I have an extended part to my question: Is it possible for me to do something like LIMIT 2 and have that return a table like with only the top two res(VR and CS)?

Comment: Just adding LIMIT 2 to the subquery should limit it to the top two res (due to the **inner** join), but still show all their loc sums; if you only want the highest locs of the list res, put the limit 2 at the very end of the whole query.

Comment: The above comment should say _if you only want the highest locs of the **highest** res_

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need is to `ORDER BY` the sum of `rent` in descending order:

```
SELECT res, loc, SUM(rent) 
FROM testTable 
GROUP BY res, loc
ORDER BY SUM(rent) DESC
```